# Slavery, God and Prayers

Tags: aristotle

I was hearing discussion among a group of philosophy students over Aristotle agruing that *Slavery is Natural in his work Politics*.

I too get thought after hearing them which is

*"We should worship those humans who have more than us. Let it be Power, Wealth or anything we desire. Because, those humans can give us and help us fullfill our desire. For praying to God and Worshiping God, I believe God is just ; He will never do injustice, no matter how much I pray if I do not do enough labour for what I desire God will never give me."*

In what ways does my reasoning differ from Aristotle's?

Comment: See [Natural slavery in Aristotle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_slavery): according to A, slavery is part of "nature", i.e. opart of the "organism" that is a society There is no place of God in his argument.

Comment: Please add a summary of Aristotle’s argument from his Politics.

Comment: See "On the Common Notion of Justice" of Leibniz on Slavery and the Ownership of Human Beings. Leibniz rejects the Aristotelian claim that some human beings are ‘natural slaves,’ that is, that they lack the capacity for self-government and may hence legitimately be enslaved
  https://jmphil.org/articles/10.32881/jomp.45/

Answer (score 1):

As I understand Aristotle's "Natural slavery," he makes a distinction between those humans that don't have cognitive powers,and those that do.
Those that don't, he would call "natural slaves."
Those that do, if enslaved, would rebel and cause enmity.

In your first statement, you are agreeing with Aristotle by thinking that one should submit to other humans that are in a higher position, wealthier, etc., "...because they can help us achieve our desires".

In the second statement, you imply that if we are not "slaves" to God (",,, if we don't do enough labor..."), we will get nothing from Him.  This statement would also reinforce Aristotle's premise - **if true**.  However, it is not true!  Whatever we get from God, it is due to **God's generosity,**  not because we "...labored hard for it."  Therefore, we are not God's "slaves"!

Answer (score 0):

Phillippians 2:13 for it is God who works in you to will and to act in order to fulfill his good purpose.

All the above discussion is Pelagianism or Semi-Pelagianism, incompatible with Judaism and Christianity`

and funny you should use that idea of slave to God because Jesus rejects that totally: Unworthy Servants
7 “Will any one of you who has a servant plowing or keeping sheep say to him when he has come in from the field, ‘Come at once and recline at table’? 8 Will he not rather say to him, ‘Prepare supper for me, and dress properly, and serve me while I eat and drink, and afterward you will eat and drink’? 9 Does he thank the servant because he did what was commanded? 10 So you also, when you have done all that you were commanded, say, ‘We are unworthy servants; we have only done what was our duty.’”

And notice: that is if you have done all that you were commanded -- bet YOU haven't :)